# Using Cilk reducer inside Cilk shared function

Tags: c++, xeon-phi, cilk-plus, offloading

Hi I am trying to offload some parallel work to MIC using _Cilk_Shared and _Cilk_offload.

I declare a Cilk shared function:

```
_Cilk_shared void somefun(int count)
```

In main I call this function using

```
_Cilk_offload somefun(12) ;
```

inside this function everything is expected to be offloaded to MIC;

I want to declare a Cilk reducer inside somefun, so I can then use cilk_for and append to a cilk reducer list,

but I get error:

```
error: illegal to declare an object of a class not marked _Cilk_shared, in a _Cilk_shared context
  cilk::reducer_list_append<int> rw;
```

I know I can do this with offload pragma so I should be able to this with cilk shared as well right?

I can't find concrete example of using _Cilk_shared and _Cilk_offload.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what the compiler is complaining about is that you never told it that it needed to create coprocessor code as well as host code for all the functions in the reducer_list_append class. It is necessary but not sufficient to declare the object rw as being needed on the coprocessor. You also need to say that the class can be used on the coprocessor.

Because you are using shared memory programming, you probably already have something like the following in your program:

```
#pragma offload_attribute (push, _Cilk_shared) 
#include <vector> 
#include <offload.h> 
#pragma offload_attribute (pop)
```

If rw is going to in shared memory, try adding the headers for reducer_list_append between those pragma's as well and use the shared allocator. If you don't need rw to be in shared memory, you shouldn't need the shared allocator. In that case, you might also be able to put the header for the class in a simple offload_attribute region, instead of a _Cilk_shared offload_attribute region - assuming there are no dependencies - but as long as you already have a _Cilk_shared offload_attribute region you might as well use it. It won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to put cilk library in offload_attribute _Cilk_shared:

```
#pragma offload_attribute (push,_Cilk_shared)
#include <cilk/cilk.h>
#include <cilk/cilk_api.h>
#include <cilk/reducer_list.h>
#pragma offload_attribute (pop)
```

Also....I found 2 interesting facts as of now:

1. it's better not put #define anywhere...it will give weird runtime bug.
2. Put #define in offload_attribute as much as you can..if you put them outside sometimes it will give weird error.

Hope Intel fixes this for knights landing.

Comment: Sorry it takes me so long to put an answer together - it meant you ending up having to figure it out by your self. As far as the define issue, it depends on what you are defining. If you need the define on the coprocessor, you should put the define in an offload region.

Comment: If I want to define on both host and coprocessor, I should only put it in offload region.. This is what I found, otherwise the runtime error occurs sometimes For example the cilk library header..